# Forcing dataframe recalculation after a change of a specific cell

Tags: pandas

I start with a simple

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'units':[30,20]})
```

And I get

```
      units
 0      30
 1      20
```

I then add a row to total the column:

```
my_sum = df.sum()
df = df.append(my_sum, ignore_index=True)
```

Finally, I add a column to calculate percentages off of the 'units' column:

```
df['pct'] = df.units / df.units[:-1].sum()
```

ending with this:

```
    units   pct
 0  30     0.6
 1  20     0.4
 2  50     1.0
```

So far so good - but now the question: I want to change the middle number of units from 20 to, for example, 30. I can use this:

```
df3.iloc[1, 0] = 40
```

or

```
df3.iat[1, 0] = 40
```

which change the cell, but the calculated values at both the last row and second column don't change to reflect it:

```
    units   pct
 0  30      0.6
 1  40      0.4
 2  50      1.0
```

How do I force these calculated values to adjust following the change in that particular cell?

Comment: pandas is not excel the value is just value , there is not function behind it  ..

Comment: @W_B - what do you mean? `df.sum()` is a function, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function that calculates it

```
def f(df):
  return df.append(df.sum(), ignore_index=True).assign(
      pct=lambda d: d.units / d.units.iat[-1])

df.iat[1, 0] = 40

f(df)

   units       pct
0     30  0.428571
1     40  0.571429
2     70  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks; so to force recalculations, you need to regenerate the dataframe and add the calculated values dynamically through the function. Good to know!